# Is there any way to update a certain git submodule by dependabot?

Tags: github, dependabot

There are many git submodules under the `contrib` directory of my repo. I want to configure my dependabot to only update `contrib/proxy`, How can I do this?

According to [this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuring-dependabot-version-updates), I find a `directory` config item. However, seems this must be equal to where `.git` is.

Should I use a `allow` config for `contrib/proxy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following works

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "gitsubmodule"
    directory: "/"
    allow:
      - dependency-name: "contrib/proxy"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```